# Sending arguments to the command line

Tags: c#, .net, command-line-arguments

I need to unzip a compressed file with the command line version of 7zip.  This one liner should to the trick:

```
Process.Start("cmd", @"C:\Users\cw\Downloads\7za920\7za e C:\UPDATED.zip -oc:\");
```

I'm specifying the path to the 7zip command line executable, and telling it which file to unzip.  If I copy and paste those arguments into my command line window, it will work.  In C#, it will bring up a command line window, and nothing will happen.  What gives?

Comment: the process you are starting is cmd, which is a command line.  You don't need to do this.  Just call the 7zip executable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
Process.Start("cmd", @"/c C:\Users\cw\Downloads\7za920\7za e C:\UPDATED.zip -oc:\");
```

Answer (score 4):

It's because you're running cmd.exe, and not 7za directly. You can do either of the two:

```
Process.Start(@"C:\users\...\7za", "e c:\updated.zip -oc:\");
```

*or*

```
Process.Start("cmd", @"/c c:\users\...\7za e c:\updated.zip -oc:\");
```

The /c flag tells cmd to run the arguments after starting.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
Process.Start(@"C:\Users\cw\Downloads\7za920\7za.exe", @"e C:\UPDATED.zip -oc:\");
```